# Unexpected OptimisticLockingException on MongoTemplate.save

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Using MongoTemplate I'm trying to store an entity called Person. Since I want to use optimistic locking, the entity is versioned using the @Version annotation.

When I try to store a new Person entity into an empty collection using MongoTemplate.save, I get OptimisticLockingException. I didn't expect this, since I'm creating a new object rather than updating an existing one. (And no other thread is accessing the collection.)

Is this expected behavior, or am I doing something wrong?

(If I use MongoOperations.insert instead, everything works. (I want to use save though, since CrudRepository only has save, not update.) If I remove the @Version annotation, it works as well.)

Thanks,
Daniel

My entity class:

```
import org.bson.types.ObjectId;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Version;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document;

@Document
public class Person {

    @Version
    private long versionId;

    @Id
    private ObjectId id;

    private final String name;

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public long getVersionId() {
        return versionId;
    }

    public ObjectId getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;

        Person person = (Person) o;

        if (id != null ? !id.equals(person.id) : person.id != null) return false;

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id != null ? id.hashCode() : 0;
    }
}
```

My test setup (which is using EmbedMongo to set up a MongoDb instance):

```
import com.mongodb.Mongo;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodExecutable;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodProcess;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.MongodStarter;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.config.MongodConfig;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.mongo.distribution.Version;
import de.flapdoodle.embed.process.runtime.Network;
import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.springframework.data.mapping.context.MappingContext;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoOperations;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.SimpleMongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;

public class MongoDbTest {

    private MongodExecutable mongodExe;
    private MongodProcess mongod;
    private Mongo mongo;
    private MongoOperations mongoOperations;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        MongodStarter runtime = MongodStarter.getDefaultInstance();

        mongodExe = runtime.prepare(new MongodConfig(Version.Main.V2_0, 12345, Network.localhostIsIPv6()));
        mongod = mongodExe.start();
        mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 12345);

        MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory = new SimpleMongoDbFactory(mongo, "database");

        MappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();
        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(mongoDbFactory, mappingContext);

        mongoOperations = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, mappingMongoConverter);
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
       mongod.stop();
       mongodExe.stop();
    }

    @Test
    public void testSave() {
        Person person = new Person("Joe");
        mongoOperations.save(person);  // This call throws OptimisticLockingException.
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When version property has type long it has 0 value by default which seems to be not acceptable by Spring Data MongoDB.

Change type of versionId in Person class into Long/Integer.

```java
@Version
private Long versionId;
```

Comment: Thanks Maciej, this confirms my understanding after looking at the code Spring Data MongoDb. My tests also show that Long failed in some case (don't remember exactly which at the moment), but Integer seems to work well.